# Non-example of a lemma on continuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity, examples-counterexamples

> **Lemma:**
>   Let $f:(X,\mathcal{T})\longrightarrow(X',\mathcal{T'})$ be a mapping  between topological spaces where $$X=\cup_{j=1}^m F_j$$
>   $ \text{ with }F_j\text{ closed for }\mathcal{T},\, f_{|F_j} \text{ continuous },\forall j=1,\ldots,m.$
>   Then $f$ is continuous.

I'd like to find a non-example to that when $X$ is a **countably** infinite union of closed sets.
My course already provides one that I find counterintuitive as I've mostly worked so far on metric spaces (the identity between $\mathbb{N}=\cup\{n\}$ with the cofinite topology and $\mathbb{N}$ with the discrete topology).
Is it possible to find one where both spaces are $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology ?
I've considered disjoint closed $X_n$ that increasingly cover $\mathbb{R}$ but in vain.

Comment: Why do you write finite union, and then ask for countably union? The result is true for finite unions, because finite union of closed sets is closed.

Comment: I'm asking about a counterexample to the statement, that's why I'm looking for a countably **infinite** union

Comment: The statement as written as true. It becomes false when the finite union is replaced by an infinite union.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should have said that I'm looking for a **non-example** when the union is infinite and not "counter-example"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any function $f$ from $\mathbb R$ into itself. For each $x\in\mathbb R$, $f|_{\{x\}}$ is continuous and $\{x\}$ is closed. But $f$ doesn't have to be continuous.

---

As another exemple, consider $f\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ such that $f(0)=0$ and that $f(x)=1$ otherwise. Then $f$ is discontinuous, but if you define $I_0=\{0\}$ and, for each natural $n$, $I_n=\left[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]$, then the restriction of $f$ to each $I_n$ is continuous, whereas $f$ is discontinuous.

Comment: I was going for a countably infinite union, so I'll edit the post, but thanks, this one didn't cross my mind !

Comment: @deque I've added another example to my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry if this seems trivial, but how do you prove that the restrictions are continuous and the overall function isn't ?  In the case of *R* with the standard topology it's easy with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition but I can't wrap my head around the subspace topologies at play here.

Comment: Epsilon delta can be used on metric subspaces too..

Comment: @deque You do it *exactly* how you would have done it with $\mathbb R$.